# Parsing a SAML Response object using OpenSSO

Tags: java, saml, opensso

I'm trying to do something that seems rather simple but am getting unexpected results.  I'm using the OpenSSO library to parse a SAML 1.1 Response, provided as a String of XML.  Since I have a sample Response from the client I've set up a simple unit test just to verify that I can parse it but get the following errors:

```
com.sun.identity.saml.protocol.Response.parseXML(<xml string>)

...

libSAML:04/21/2011 02:16:46:983 PM EDT: Thread[main,5,main]
Assertion.parseAssertionElement:
libSAML:04/21/2011 02:16:46:984 PM EDT: Thread[main,5,main]
Assertion.parseAssertionElement: minMinorVersion = 0, maxMinorVersion = 1
libSAML:04/21/2011 02:16:46:987 PM EDT: Thread[main,5,main]
AuthenticationStatement:Wrong element Subjectincluded.
```

There are Subject nodes in both the AuthenticationStatement and the AttributeStatement.

I simply want to parse the provided XML, check the status and pull out the NameIdentifier.  This is entirely new to me so please excuse the ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything about the "Subjectincluded" element in SAML specs. Please review your XML. If this is some kind of an extension to SAML, I think it will be safe to simply remove that element.

Comment: I believe that's a typo.  That's actually what I see but I believe it should read "Subject included".  If I remove the Subject from the AttributeStatement node the message doesn't change but if I remove it from the AuthenticationStatement it tells me "AuthenticationStatement should contain one subject."

Comment: Then check that you have correct namespace in your XML. Should be "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion". You may want to add the namespace declaration to the root element if its not there...

Comment: Example: <saml:Assertion
   xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"....

Comment: Namespace declaration is there however in my case it's 1.1.

Comment: Hmm... according to the source code it is expected to be 1.0. Please try replacing 1.1 -> 1.0